Matrix norm inequality involving triangle inequality
Consider the following norm:
$$ T = ||mge_3 + \frac{m}{k_v}\cdot(k_x\xi + k_1\cdot (\xi-q)+ k_2\cdot(\xi-q+w)|| \ \ (1) $$
where $m,k_v,k_1,k_2 > 0$ constant scalars and $\xi, q, w\in \mathbb{R}^{3x1}$. The z-axis unitary vector is denoted as $e_3=[0 \ 0 \ 1]^T$. Consider, also, a Lyapunov function candidate:
$$ S = \frac{1}{2}k_x||\xi||^2 + \frac{1}{2}k_v||v||^2 + \frac{1}{2}k_1||\xi-q||^2+\frac{1}{2}k_2||\xi-q+w||^2 \ \ (2) $$
By using the triangle inequality on (1) and considering $k_{max}=max(k_x,k_1,k_2)$, one gets the following:
$$ T \geq mg - \frac{m}{k_v}k_{max}\cdot (||\xi|| + ||\xi-q||+||\xi-q+w||) \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow T \geq mg - 3\frac{m}{k_v}k_{max}\cdot (||\xi||^2 + ||v||^2 + ||\xi-q||^2 + ||\xi-q+w|| ^2)^{1/2} \ \ (3) $$
I am trying to figure out how to get from (1) to (3). I imagine that the reverse triangle inequality has to be used but I have not managed to get it anywhere. The equations are from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4209176 (Remark 1).

First, by triangle inequality $\|x + y\| \ge \big|\|x\| - \|y\|\big| \ge \|x\| - \|y\|$, from (1), we have
$$T \ge \|mg e_3\| - \left\|\frac{m}{k_v}\cdot(k_x\xi + k_1\cdot (\xi-q)+ k_2\cdot(\xi-q+w)\right\|.$$
Then,
$$T \ge mg - \frac{m}{k_v}(\|k_x\xi\| + \|k_1(\xi - q)\| + \|k_2(\xi - q + w)\|).$$
Then,
$$T \ge mg -  \frac{m}{k_v}k_{\max}
(\|\xi\| + \|\xi - q\| + \|\xi - q + w\|).$$
Then, using $a + b + c\le \sqrt{3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)}$, we have
$$T \ge mg - \frac{m}{k_v}k_{\max}
\sqrt{3(\|\xi\|^2 + \|\xi - q\|^2 + \|\xi - q + w\|^2)}.$$
Then, using $3 > \sqrt{3}$,
$$T \ge mg - 3\frac{m}{k_v}k_{\max}
\sqrt{\|\xi\|^2 + \|\xi - q\|^2 + \|\xi - q + w\|^2}.$$
Then,
$$T \ge mg - 3\frac{m}{k_v}k_{\max}
\sqrt{\|\xi\|^2 + \|v\|^2 + \|\xi - q\|^2 + \|\xi - q + w\|^2}.$$

Does the inequality $a+b+c \leq \sqrt{3\cdot(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})}$ have a specific name?

@TeoProtoulis It is the AM-QM inequality.
